# What is the use of System Environment Variables?

Tags: environment-variables

I am the beginner for visual studio IDE. While I was assigned the project in the Visual studio IDE. I was asked to create system environment variable as ACE for ACE Lib files. Could any one please tell me why we configuring the system environment variable. What they actually mean ?

My doubt is what is environment variable ? 
How it communicate with the IDE ? Why it is so important to setup environment variable ?

(Please correct me If I got anything wrong here)

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to accomplish - it sounds more like you are looking for adding to the `PATH` variable. Also if your question isn't about customizing Visual Studio itself, you should tag your question with the according programming language tag (C#, etc.).

Comment: Visual Studio is a platform? its a IDE -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio

Comment: Thanks @Filburt 
I have edited from platform to IDE. I also understood that VS is an Integrated Development Environment , not a platform. My Doubt is what is environment variable ? How it communicate with the IDE ? Why it is so important to setup environment variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to change the path stored in EnvironmentVariable, some thing like this,

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

or else you need to Create, modifie, or delete an environment variable stored in the current process,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx

Adding more details in your question might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Joy . All I need is what is environment variable ? How it actually works ?

Comment: @Jeyasuriya http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058111/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-in-visual-studio-2010 refer this, hope it is helpful